# PHP 5.3 fgetcsv \"

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I'm importing a CSV from DB2 into MySQL, all goes well until half a million rows in I encounter \" from a column with encrypted data.

Here is an example:

```
100,"foo","bar","µ┬;¬µ┬;→ºµ┬;Öì\"
101,"foo","bar","$⌠ù¶∙$∙µ┬µ┬;→ºµ┬;Öì"
```

When fgetcsv parses this, it escapes the last double quote and includes the next line as if it is part of that field.

I see a few bug reports and in PHP 5.3 they added an escape param for fgetcsv.

What does DB2 use as an escape? Just "?

Comment: Actually I can't set the escape char to an empty string as it must be a single char.

Comment: Maybe use `chr(0)` as the escape character?

Comment: Excellent suggestion Alin, I think that may work as well. I'm attempting another import with " as the escape char, it's going well so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments on the [`fgetcsv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) manual page it looks like this is a fairly common issue with no real good workaround.  There are however some alternate functions which people have been kind enough to post on the page which might do what you need.

Here is a link to one of them: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php#98800

Comment: Yea, I had tried that before coming here, this file also contains binary data and that seems to break when I used that function, for whatever reason. Also, it throws a lot of notices because it doesn't set the field before appending, just messy.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure if you really want to use PHP as a database migration tool.  You might want to look around for *real* migration toolkits.

Comment: Fair enough, especially with an unfamiliar dbms. Just realized these timestamps have microtime.

Comment: The fgetcsv() is a disaster. And the suggestion in the function comments you referred to unfortunately didn't work for me. Not sure why something that isn't stable is in. Never had these issues on Rails.